# Sliding text overlapping

Tags: jquery, text, overlap, slide

Having a slight issue with a slider plugin for Wordpress I am creating. I'm trying to get the text to slideUp at the beginning and slideDown just before the transition to the next image. This appears to work fine however after a few transition the slider that fades (top one) text starts to overlap; the text from the next image shows before the slide has changed.

And the code segment:

http://pastebin.com/3WxgRWdg

Thanks to anyone that can help. Really would appreciate it. Matthew.

Comment: Can anyone help me out? Here it a link to an example.

http://www.matthewruddy.com/premiumslider/

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your animation for the *other* one, check out the complete function:

```
var text = '.lof-main-item-desc';
$(text).slideUp(200);
this.wrapper.stop().delay(200).animate(obj, {
    duration: this.settings.duration,
    easing: this.settings.easing,
    complete: function() {
        $(text).slideDown(200);
    }
});
```

What this is doing is finding **all** `.lof-main-item-desc` and affecting them whether they're in another slideshow or not.  You need to make it affect only the ones in the current show by only looking within this wrapper when sliding both directions, like this:

```
var text = '.lof-main-item-desc';
$(this.wrapper).find(text).slideUp(200);
this.wrapper.stop().delay(200).animate(obj, {
    duration: this.settings.duration,
    easing: this.settings.easing,
    complete: function() {
        $(this).find(text).slideDown(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: This sortof works however now the text isn't sliding down. See the example link above to see what I mean. Check the top slider.

Comment: @Matthew - I don't see any text on your example page either...I'm confused, since there's no text `<div>` elements in the HTML either, am I missing something?